# Error Downloading file in Asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download a file from server path in asp.net, but I get an error.

local host:3332 says:

> error while downloading file

Here is my code:

```
public override void DownloadArchiveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string filename, filepath;
    try
    {
        string wc = "ID='" + this.ARCHTECHDOC_ID.Text + "'";
        ARCHTECHDOCRecord rec = ARCHTECHDOCTable.GetRecord(wc);
        // Get the record.
        if (rec != null)
        {   
            // Get the name of the attachment.
            filename = rec.DOCTITLE;
            if (rec.PARENTPHYSICALPATH_ID != null)
            {
                ARCHDOCLIBRecord recARCHDOCLIB = ARCHDOCLIBTable.GetRecord("ID='"+rec.PARENTPHYSICALPATH_ID+"'");
                if (recARCHDOCLIB!=null)
                {
                    filepath =Convert.ToString(recARCHDOCLIB.URL);
                    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                    response.ClearContent();
                    response.Clear();
                    response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");
                    response.TransmitFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath));
                    response.Flush();
                    response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Is `recARCHDOCLIB.URL` containing absolute path in the server or just an external URL link to other server? If it's an external file URL, try remove `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` when doing `TransmitFile`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto its absolute path in server i remove it but not working

Comment: Is the downloading process returns `PlatformNotSupportedException` or `ThreadAbortException`? Try debugging the code and find out which exception being thrown there & in which line it's thrown, post relevant contents of that exception too.

Comment: You could start with checking `File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath))` or more generally, checking the value of filepath and its mapped physical path against your expectations.